# How to connect to dynamics crm by ClientSecret in asp.net mvc web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

When I used the authtype clientsecret for the console application, it worked, however for the web application, (authtyp) AD was changed automatically insted of clientSecret and it is not working. Please help how can i achieve on asp.net mvc web application.

> Note : The same code runs successfully on a console program but fails
> on a web application.

Please find my code below.

Connection String :

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyCrm1" connectionString="authtype=ClientSecret;url=https://fake.crm11.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc;clientid=fd0a8505-e559-4145-b1c8-929d0c9e0ce1;ClientSecret=CVm8Q~hfG0K1Itm-CSGWk1dOtO54T2ghPHmlNc7K;LoginPrompt=False;redirectUri=app://fd0a8505-e559-4145-b1c8-929d0c9e0ce1;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

ASP.net MVC C#

```
 private static IOrganizationService _crmServiceClient()
        {
            using (var connection = new CrmServiceClient(_connectionString))
            {
                if (connection.IsReady)
                {
                     _service = (IOrganizationService)connection.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)connection.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)connection.OrganizationServiceProxy;

                }
            }

            return _service;

        }
```

[image: Connection is null on CRMServiceClient]

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask you why do you need this helper code:

```
_service = (IOrganizationService)connection.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)connection.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)connection.OrganizationServiceProxy;
```

Your connection implements IOrganizationService interface so can be perfectly used for any kind of CRUD and Execute operations.

Comment: If it is a helper class, we can do basic operations and comprehend the code with ease. After Latest dll Updating  Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies.9.0.2.50. It is working on Asp.net mvc application.